# why file is not downloaded properly when clicked from datatable using primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

my p:fileDownload is not working properly in a datatable. when I click on a commandbutton in a row it downloads the file properly. but then, I when I click on the button on another one row it downloads the previous file. It is behaving differently with txt files. When I download a txt files it also downloads the previous txt file, but when I open them, it turns like the content is mixed with the previous one. Sometimes with wierd characters. (the files are stored in a database)

Here is my bean:

```
public StreamedContent fileDownload(File file)
{
    byte[] bytes = (byte[]) file.getFilebytes();
    InputStream ist = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    StreamedContent download = new DefaultStreamedContent(ist, "application/"+file.getFiletype(), file.getFiletype());
    return download;
}
```

and here is my jsf page:

```
<p:dataTable id="Files" value="#{files.getFilesFromAssignments(as)}" var ="fil">
    <p:column style="border:0">
        <p:commandLink title="Download" ajax="false">
            <p:graphicImage value="/Pics/download.png" style="border:0"/>
            <p:fileDownload value="#{files.fileDownload(fil)}"/>
         </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

here is my File entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FILE")
public class FileKeys implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "FILEBYTES")
    private Serializable filebytes;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FILETYPE")
    private String filetype;


    //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: What version of Primefaces and JSF implementation are you using?  I have seen similar behavior.

Comment: @maple_shaft I'm using JSF 2.0, and PrimeFaces 3.0.M2. Also tried 2.2.1

Comment: In the line `public StreamedContent fileDownload(File file)`, what library does the class `File` come from. I was thinking it was `java.io.File`, but just found out that it does not have `getFilebytes()` method.

Comment: @BheshG The File type is a class that I have defined. the bytes of this file can be retrieved from file.getFileBytes(). The file is getting downloaded properly at the first time. But the problem is when I download another file. It seems to be caused by the PrimeFaces

Comment: I am using JSF 2.0 and PrimeFaces 2.2.1. If you want me to try it on my machine, please post the code for your File class.

Comment: @fareed: You are right something is wrong, I got exactly the same result as you described.

Comment: @BheshG: I have updated my question you can get my file class here.

Comment: @fareed: Might be a PrimeFaces bug.

Comment: @BheshG: Yeah Im gussing that too.. Anyway, thanx for trying! :)

Answer (score 0):

Mine is Primefaces5.1, and JSF2.2. There are no problems.
I think the bug has been fixed by Primefaces.